# When all hardware resources are free what would cause linux to run slowly

Tags: ubuntu, performance, gnome3

Sometimes, after a few hours, my system works slowly. I have checked status of these resources:

- Hard disk using `iotop`
- Ram usage using `free`
- CPU usage using `top`

None of them are busy. `top` also shows that there is no process using too much memory or cpu.

Slowness is in switching between windows, typing, etc...

Is there anything else I should check?

Comment: if possible post `top` output , and also check in logs for any error.

Comment: If GUI-related things slow down, it may be a video driver / hardware fault: try Unity 2D if possible.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check to see if your disk drive is having problems.  I've had cases over the years when drives get a little warm they do a lot of retries before getting the data and thus the system really acts slow.

Comment: Or accumulating bad blocks if the drive doesn't automagically compensate.

Answer (score 1):

Analyzing `top` output may give much more information than simple CPU load. For example: `load average` shows average number of blocked processes waiting for resources. It could be CPU or IO. Three number represent period of time of 1 minute, 5 minute or 15 minutes, respectively. `%wa` column represents percentage of processor time waiting for IO.

I guess it could be useful to collect some information for analysis:

```
# nohup sar -A -o /tmp/sar.out.bin 10 1440 &
# nohup vmstat -t 10 1440 > /tmp/vmstat.log  &
# nohup top -bc -d 10 -n 1440 > /tmp/top.log &
```